# how to autoincrement different department in one table in textbox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

This is my code for autoincrementing but when i save it in database the number of autoincrement is starting to 1 again. I need something that is stable where in there are different incremeting in each department and also when the year change it starts from 1 again.
An example output should be :

```
10-ppmn-16-0001
10-fcrsm-16-0001


 Static cnt As Integer
        cnt = cnt + 1


prnotxt.Text = ""10""-"" & deptcmb.Text & "-" & Now.Date.ToString("yy") & "-" & Format(cnt, "0000") & ""
```

Comment: can you make your cnt equal a dlookup to lookup the max(IncrementField) +1. You could use a where clause for the department?

Comment: so should i put dlook up in my database code ?

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of what you want to save, and whether your application is attached to any database or not, there is a facility in VB.NET to save values into permanent storage.

1. Right click on your `Project`, and click on `Properties`. This will open the `Project Properties`.
2. Goto `Settings` tab and add a setting with appropriate Name, Type, Scope and default value. For the sake of example, say our setting is Name=DeptCount, Type=Integer, Scope=User, Value=0

   [image]
3. Now you can easily save and get the saved value across application restarts. Sample code provided below:

   ```
   '-- to save the value in settings.
   My.Settings.DeptCount = 100
   My.Settings.Save()

   '-- to get back the saved value
   Dim count As Integer = My.Settings.DeptCount
   ```

Comment: No when i change my department it continouslyincrement

Comment: This answer just shows you how to store your value in a persistent medium. It will not automatically reset. You need to reset it whenever you need to do that from code.